# Thread-safe events - is this a “clean” way? - 2

Tags: c#, multithreading

Assuming the constructive criticism in this thread [Thread-safe events - is this a "clean" way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069174/thread-safe-events-is-this-a-clean-way/34069333?noredirect=1#comment55902241_34069333) I sat down and tried to read me in the whole thematics of multithreading.

Here's some code with the same base question: Is this an established way to create a non-freezing UI using events?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void MyThreadUpdateHandler(string s);

    public event MyThreadUpdateHandler MyThreadUpdate;
    System.Threading.Thread MyThread;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void DoTheCount()
    {
        int a = 0;

        while (a < int.MaxValue)
        {
            if (a % 1000000 == 0)
            {
                this.MyThreadUpdate(a.ToString());
            }

            a++;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MyThreadUpdate(string s)
    {
        this.lblEvent.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate ()
        {
            lblEvent.Text = s;
        });
    }

    private void btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyThreadUpdate += Form1_MyThreadUpdate;

        if (MyThread == null)
            MyThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoTheCount));

        lblStatus.Text = "Starting thread";


        if (MyThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Unstarted)
            MyThread.Start();

    }

    private void btnAbortThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

However there's something I still don't get. Why are some examples using a Program() like this one? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667298/Using-ThreadStaticAttribute

Thank you :)

Comment: The article you linked is about a CONSOLE app, not a windowed app, so it is quite different.

Comment: Ah well that clears things a little bit. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to get? your question is confusing...

Comment: I want to know if this is an established way to create a non-freezing UI using events.

Comment: Threads clean themselves up when they have no more code to execute. Please don't abort threads.

Comment: This was just for testing for me. I've tried some Thread methods.

Comment: I'd use Task instead of Thread directly
Tasks are more handy and at higher level than Thread, and i suggest to use them with  await/async

Comment: [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) is the established way of doing it.

Comment: @KosalaW Established does not mean good. The best way to do this is to do it single threaded.

Comment: @Aron: Did you mean to ask OP to do it in the UI thread? Is that the answer OP is looking for?

Comment: @KosalaW In this case, yes, it would be that events should be handled on the UI thread (for a UI application, single theaded, means on the UI thread). This example is far too artificial to be interesting, as it is unnecessarily CPU bound. The problem that the OP is facing is that his program is slow if he doesn't use "threading" but it will cause exceptions if he uses non-UI thread. The simplest solution (in .net 4.5+) is to use "Green Thread like" (ie async await) constructs/co-threads, unless he is CPU bound.

Comment: @Aron As far as I can understand, he is looking for a way to update a UI component during a long running task.

Comment: You're both right. I have to do a lot of hardware interaction i.e. com-port access. It may lead to a com port timeout which is at least 2 secounds. I don't like my UI to be blocked until the data is beeing read. But before I'm starting to rewrite the lib from my initial post (sie link above) I'd like to have a good way to head to before changing a whole bunch of code and seeing that it was a dead end :)

Comment: @KosalaW Ah...I didn't read his previous post. He actually fits into one of 3 situations where I would call threading "allowed". External library call that takes a long time.

Comment: @AllDayPiano Okay, I've posted an answer based on how to do it with Rx.Net (or MS.net's new event model).

Answer (score 3):

> However there's something I still don't get. Why are some examples
>   using a Program() like this one?
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667298/Using-ThreadStaticAttribute

the code is

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prog = new Program();

        //define the threads
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(prog.ThreadFunc1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(prog.ThreadFunc2));
```

This allowed the developer to call instance funcitons `public void ThreadFunc1()` & `public void ThreadFunc2()`
 from static funciton - `static void Main(string[] args)`

**Update 1**

Established way to create a non-freezing UI,  is to do all the time consuming activity on a separate thread & marshal the call to UI thread **only** to update to it.
What you have implemented follows the  same idea.

Just one point I would like to mention, although it has nothing to do with freezing of UI.

instead of `System.Threading.Thread`,  Please use `ThreadPool`.

`Task`, `BackgroundWorker`, `System.Threading.Timer`, `Asynchronous Programming Model` all use a thread from `ThreadPool`. or you may also use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`

There are very special cases when one should use `System.Threading.Thread` instead of a thread from `ThreadPool`

Comment: Thank you Kapoor, I'll have a closer look to this :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let me say, I feel sorry for you, trying to work with a legacy library.

Okay. You qualify for one of the few reasons I would work with threading in .net

> Running a Legacy library for a long time

Now, reading your previous code, I feel that you want to use Rx.Net for project.

I would start by creating a `IObservable` for your library.

```
public static class LibraryHelper
{
    public static IObservable<EventPattern<StatusChangedEventArg>> StatusObservable(this ComLibrary com)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArg>, StatusChangedEventArg>(x => com.FooEvent +=x, x => com.FooEvent -= x);
    }
}
```

This shall allow you to use Rx.Net with your library, like so...

```
private async void btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComLibary com = new ComLibray();

    lblStatus.Text = "Starting thread";

    // using is there to unsubscribe after the call, to prevent a memory leak.
    var subscription = com.StatusObservable()
       //Magic sauce 
       //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417978/how-to-get-a-winform-synchronization-context-or-schedule-on-a-winform-thread
      .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
      .Subscribe(@event => {
         //Do something on the UI thread
      });
   using(subscription)
   {
           //Task.Run uses a background thread to get the data from your COM

          var result = await Task.Run(()=> com.Read());
           //back in UI thread. Do stuff.
    }
}
```